# how to connect to sql after comfirm information after submit

Tags: php, sql

after user submited their information , the system have to comfirm that they had enter corrert information.....
so here is the comfimation page.....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>

<title>Page Title Goes Here</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form1.css"/>
<body onload="disableSubmit()">

<div id="wrapper">

<h1>Comfirm submission </h1>

<nav> 
    <ul>
         <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="findoutmore.html">Find out more</a></li>
         <li><a href="offer.html">Offer</a></li>
         <li><a href="credit.html">Credit</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Admin</a></li>
         <li><a href="wireframe.html">WireFrame</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<?php 

session_start();

$forename = $_SESSION['forename'];
$surname = $_SESSION['surname'];
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$postalAddress = $_SESSION['postalAddress'];
$landLineTelNo = $_SESSION['landLineTelNo'];
$mobileTelNo = $_SESSION['mobileTelNo'];
$sendMethod = $_SESSION['sendMethod'];

echo "<p>Forename :  $forename <p/>";
echo "<p>Surname : $surname <p/>";

if($_SESSION['postalAddress']==NULL)
{echo "<p>postalAddress:NULL</p>";} 
else {echo "<p>PostalAddress : $postalAddress </p>";}

if($_SESSION['email']==NULL)
{echo "<p>email:NULL<p/>";} 
else {echo "<p>email : $email</p>";}

if($_SESSION['landLineTelNo']==NULL)
{echo "<p>landLineTelNo:NULL<p/>";} 
else {echo "<p>landLineTelNo : $landLineTelNo </p>";}

if($_SESSION['mobileTelNo']==NULL)
{echo "<p>mobileTelNo:NULL<p/>";} 
else {echo "<p>mobileTelNo : $mobileTelNo </p>";}

echo "<p>sendMethod : $sendMethod </p>";            

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        //sql sever
         $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", '',"chollerton");

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "<p>Connection failed:".mysqli_connect_error()."</p>\n";
        }

        mysql_select_db("ct_expressedinterest",$con);

        $datasql ="INSERT INTO ct_expressedinterest(expressInterestID, forename, surname,postalAddress,landLineTelNo,mobileTelNo,email,sendMethod)
                                                VALUES ('$_POST[forename]','$_POST[surname]','$_POST[postalAddress]','$_POST[landLineTelNo]','$_POST[mobileTelNo]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[sendMethod]')" ;

        mysql_query($datasql,$con);

        mysql_close($con);
}

?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

i wanted to insert the data to database.
but it seem like error in connecting to database

Comment: Try this tutorial  http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_required.asp

Comment: Try echo $datasql; to see what your query looks like. Might help you spot what is going on if you see what the created query is. You can copy and run it directly in SQL to see if there are errors.

Comment: whatever you do: filter your user input. The current SQL statement is open to SQL Injection.

Comment: You should create a separate PHP page called dbconnect.php. In that put your database connection code. Then on pages where you need to access the database use-- require_once 'dbconnect .php'; on the top of the page.

Comment: That way you if your database changes you only have to change it in one spot.